# Discord.js events won't fire

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord, discord.js

So I'm working on making a discord bot, but for some reason, event handling just won't work at all. The event files are found and all data inside of the event is fine, but it won't fire. I've tried everything I could think of, but nothing seems to work.

index.ts

```js
import { Client, GatewayIntentBits } from "discord.js";
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();

import { Bot } from "./structs/Bot";

export const bot = new Bot(new Client({
    intents: [
        (all intents for testing)
    ]
}));
```

Bot.ts

```js
export class Bot {
    public constructor(public readonly client: Client) {
        this.client.login(process.env.TOKEN!);
        this.eventHandler();
    }

    private async eventHandler() {
        const events = fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, "..", "events")).filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));
        for (const file of events) {
            const event = await import(path.join(__dirname, "..", "events", `${file}`));
            if (event.once) {
                this.client.once(event.name, (...args) => {
                    event.execute(...args);
                });
            } else {
                this.client.on(event.name, (...args) => {
                    event.execute(...args);
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ready.ts

```
import { Client } from "discord.js"

export default {
    name: "ready",
    once: false,
    async execute(client: Client) {
        console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user!.tag}`);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(event)` and `console.log(event.name)` to ensure the properties exist? Also, have you tried creating the line hard coded at the top of your function (just for testing) `this.client.on("ready", () => console.log("event works"));`?

Comment: @Tyler2P yeah, all properties exist and hardcoding events works too

Comment: How do you call `bot.eventHandler()`?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an error on your `ready.ts` file.

You should set `once:` to `true`. This works for me completely fine:

```
// JavaScript, although I don’t think it makes much difference on TypeScript
module.exports = {
    name: 'ready',
    once: true,
    async execute(client) {
      console.log('We are up, soaring the skies!')
    }
}
```

Comment: This would have no effect on the registering of event listeners. The value of .once is already handled

Comment: OP says they have tried hardcoding the event and it is working, I do not seem to find an issue anywhere but the  ready.ts file. I understand that I may be wrong, though.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work, when I had to use `event.default.name` or `event.default.execute(..args)`

Weird because I tried that before posting the question and it didn't work at all.

(New Bot.ts)

```js
export class Bot {
    public constructor(public readonly client: Client) {
        this.client.login(process.env.TOKEN!);
        this.importCommands();
        this.eventHandler();
    }

    private async eventHandler() {
        const events = fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, "..", "events")).filter(file => file.endsWith(".js") || file.endsWith(".ts"));
        for (const file of events) {
            const event = await import(path.join(__dirname, "..", "events", `${file}`));
            if (event.default.once) {
                this.client.once(event.default.name, (...args) => {
                    event.default.execute(...args);
                });
            } else {
                this.client.on(event.default.name, (...args) => {
                    event.default.execute(...args);
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```